# Getting call is rejected by callee error sometimes when i try to open excel from web application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, interop

> I am using interop excel to open excel from web application as :

```
 xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ReportURL);
                xlApp.Visible = true;
```

Randomly i am getting above mentioned error. I have also added following code to resovle but it is on local perfectly but it gives error sometimes on other user's machine.

```
 finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(addIn);
            }
```

> Does anyone have any idea what would be the reason behind ? and
>   resolution?

Comment: normally the reason why my excel's won't work on other machines is the lack of required libraries, I fixed these issues by installing `access database engine`

Comment: what is that can you please elaborate more and how installing this would fixed your issue ?

Comment: actually that is a different implementation, im opening a connection to an excel file using OleDB, the problem is after I deployed my app in a machine with no office package installed, I cannot create a connection to my excel. So installing access database engine will provide you the core excel libraries and drivers needed to process and excel file. ( No need to install MS Office)

Comment: solution  -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(v=vs.80).aspx